# Is there a way that I can conditionally return an HTTP response?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-resolver

I'm using a resolver to get information to populate my website. And I want to test the connection to the API to get the information so that if I don't get a response, I can call a local set of mocked data to ensure that the HTML works.

This is the code for my resolver:

```
this.printingService.getCvJsonResume(userId, cvId)
      .subscribe(
        (result) => {
          if (result.status === 200) {
            return this.printingService.getCvJsonResume(userId, cvId)
              .pipe(map((cv: Curriculum) => {
                if (cv) {
                  return this.toDate(cv);
                }
              }));
          }
        });
    return this.printingService.getDefaultCV()
      .pipe(map((cv: Curriculum) => {
        if (cv) {
          alert(this.i18nService.instant('defaultCvMessage'));
          return this.toDate(cv);
        }
      }));
```

But, of course, it's always returning the mocked data, even when there's a response. So what I need is to make sure that there's a condition that ensures that the response exists, and only if there's no response, then the mocked data is retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always return the mock data:

```
this.printingService.getCvJsonResume(userId, cvId)
      .subscribe(
        (result) => {
          if (result.status === 200) {
            return this.printingService.getCvJsonResume(userId, cvId)
              .pipe(map((cv: Curriculum) => {
                if (cv) {
                  return this.toDate(cv);
                }
              }));
          }
        }); // end of subscribe

    // always return mock data
    return this.printingService.getDefaultCV()
      .pipe(map((cv: Curriculum) => {
        if (cv) {
          alert(this.i18nService.instant('defaultCvMessage'));
          return this.toDate(cv);
        }
      }));
```

You just need to change the logic a little bit to call `this.printingService.getDefaultCV()` when status is not 200

```
    return this.printingService.getCvJsonResume(userId, cvId)
      .pipe(
        map(result => {
          if (result.status === 200) {
            return this.printingService.getCvJsonResume(userId, cvId);
          }

          // error then fallback to defaultCV()
          return this.printingService.getDefaultCV();
      }),
        map((cv: Curriculum) => {
          if (cv) {
            return this.toDate(cv);
          }
      }));
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to call the same service twice. Call it once check if response has data then return the data otherwise make mock data call -

```
data: any;
this.printingService.getCvJsonResume(userId, cvId)
      .subscribe(
        (result) => {
          if (result.status === 200) {
            this.data = result;
          }else  {
                   this.printingService.getDefaultCV()
                      .subscribe(result=> {
                   if (result) {
                              alert(this.i18nService.instant('defaultCvMessage'));
                          this.data = result;
                    }
                 }));
          }
        });
```